# Remembering original image after patch extraction

Tags: python, image, numpy, scikit-learn

I apologize if this is too general. I am using the PatchExtractor function in scikit-learn to convert images - an array of size = (n_images x image_height x image_width) - into patches, so the resulting array has size = (n_patches, patch_height, patch_width).

However, with this function I lose track of which patch came from which image, which is important for later in the pipeline. Is there a way to keep track of the image from which a patch came?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The patches are extracted from images in sequence, so, if you know the count of images, and patches, you can know which patch if from which image:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_extraction import image
images = np.zeros((5, 4, 4, 3))
images[:] = np.arange(5).reshape(-1, 1, 1, 1)
patches = image.PatchExtractor((2, 2)).transform(images)
n_patches = patches.shape[0] // images.shape[0]
index = np.repeat(np.arange(images.shape[0]), n_patches)
print(index, patches[:, 0, 0, 0])
```